# List Grouping - Lambda or Linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a reporting software I have been working with a list of reports. On one of our interfaces it is possible to display multiple time periods. Each report has a timeframe of 1 day and for each time period we grab out a report for each day and add them to a list of reports. This has caused a lot of messy code with working out numbers and I am attempting to refactor this.

I am having issues with a lambda expression or linq query. I would like to group all the reports into a single report. In this single report I would like all the people to be merged with their projects and cases worked on.

```
class TimeReport : Report // Report handles basic stuff like time generated, start/end //date ect.
{
     public  List<ReportPersonRow> results;
     // more methods below for handling other report details
}

class ReportPersonRow
{
    public long PersonId {get;set;}
    public string PersonName {get;set;}
    public List<ReportProjectRow> Projects {get;set;}

    // more methods below for handling other details
}

class ReportProjectRow
{
    public long ProjectId{get;set;}
    public string ProjectName{get;set;}
    public List<ReportProjectCaseRow> Projects {get;set;}

    // more methods below for handling other details
}

class ReportProjectCaseRow
{
    public long CaseId{get;set;}
    public string CaseName{get;set;}
    public string HoursLogged{get;set;}

    // more methods below for handling other details
}
```

I Originally started with and various others of even attempting to get anywhere and I'm lost in what direction to go or if I should even be doing it like this.

```
 var flatList = Model.Reports.SelectMany(x => x.Results).GroupBy(x => x.PersonId);
```

An example of what the data currently looks like and what I would like to achieve is below.

report
-person
--project
---case
--project
---case
---case
---case
--project
---case
---case
-person
--project
---case
--project
---case
---case
---case
--project
---case
---case

report
-person
--project
---case
--project
---case
---case
---case
--project
---case
---case
-person
--project
---case
--project
---case
---case
---case
--project
---case
---case

And the end result would be (all previous reports merged into 1)

report
-person
--project
---case
---case
---case
---case
--project
---case
---case
---case
--project
---case
---case
---case
---case
---case
-person
--project
---case
---case
---case
--project
---case
---case
---case
--project
---case
---case
---case
---case

Comment: I don't think you can achieve your goal with a LINQ one-liner (though I'm not too sure of what you're trying to do exactly), it might be easier to try and improve the "messy code" you mentioned.

Comment: Would all of the items in each grouping be duplicates of each other?  Or is it possible for two `ReportPersonRow`s to have the same `PersonID` but different Projects?

Comment: Martin,

Each of the reports will likely duplicate people, including personid. However each single report will never contain any duplicates of the same person.

Comment: I've updated with an example of what I expect the output to be and what the list currently may look like.

Comment: Thanks for giving an example.  Can you also add Ids for each item, like `person 1`, `project 3`, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

```
var flatlist = from r in Model.Reports
               from p in r.Results
               from c in p.Projects
               group c by p.PersonId
               into grp;
               select grp;
```

maybe? im not really sure exactly what you want. this would create a list of ReportProjectRow's that are grouped by the person id.

"I would like to group all the reports into a single report. In this single report I would like all the people to be merged with their projects and cases worked on."

This would take all the reports, find all the people in those reports, find all the projects from all of those people, and then group the projects under the person ID. from there you can manipulate the information however you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the GroupBy first

```
var flatList = Model.results.GroupBy(r => r.PersonId)
                            .Select(group => new { Group = group.Key, Results = group.SelectMany(x => x.Projects) });
```

You may need to tweak the query as it might not be returning exactly what you're looking for but you should get the idea. The group parameter of the Select is a sub collection of all entities for a unique PersonId.